# How do the servers mark the email as read

Tags: email, email-server, imap, pop3

I'm looking to know how servers mark emails as read and unread with IMAP or POP.

I've logged into my server (using cPanel) and navigated to my `mail` directory and downloaded the same email file, both read and unread, and used a file comparator on them, only to find both email files were identical.

If I move all my `mail` directory to a different server, how does it know which emails have been already read?

---

**Update**
One thing I notice from this two files is that the content is identical but there was a subtil change in the file name, the letter **S** was added at the end.

```
Unread: 1507345332.M378557P5...,S=78315,W=80152-2,c
Read:   1507345332.M378557P5...,S=78315,W=80152-2,Sc
```

Following the [link](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/MailboxFormat/Maildir#Filename_examples) provided by @rAlen I was able to see that the **S** stands for **Seen** and is added as soon as the email is read.

Answer (score 4):

cPanel uses dovecot as POP3/IMAP server.

Messages that are read are moved from new to cur folder.

From: https://wiki2.dovecot.org/MailboxFormat/Maildir

---

**Directory Structure**

By default Dovecot uses Maildir++ directory layout for organizing mailbox directories. This means that all the folders are directly inside ~/Maildir directory:

- ~/Maildir/new, ~/Maildir/cur and ~/Maildir/tmp directories contain
  the messages for INBOX. The tmp directory is used during delivery,
  new messages arrive in new and read shall be moved to cur by the
  clients.
- ~/Maildir/.folder/ is a mailbox folder
- ~/Maildir/.folder.subfolder/ is a subfolder of a folder (ie.
  "folder/subfolder")

You can also optionally use the "fs" layout by appending :LAYOUT=fs to mail_location. This makes the folder structure look like:

- ~/Maildir/new, ~/Maildir/cur and ~/Maildir/tmp directories contain the messages for INBOX, just like with Maildir++.
- ~/Maildir/folder/ is a mailbox folder
- ~/Maildir/folder/subfolder/ is a subfolder of a folder

---

Comment: thank you @rAlen, initially I thought the same, that it would move emails around from different directories, but I currently have 3 unread emails in my inbox and my `~/Maildir/new` is empty